# Silverlight development compatibility issues

Tags: ios, macos, silverlight, applet

I have a Silverlight based web site, and I am wondering whether it is compatible for Apple related devices, like MacBook, MacAir, iPad or iPhone? Compatible I mean whether end user could browse Silverlight based web site using MacBook, MacAir, iPad or iPhone? If not, any changes I need to make (if there is any free software which could enable Silverlight browse on such devices without development efforts, it will be great)? Appreciate if any related technical documents could be provided for developer perspective (i.e. how to support Silverlight on such Apple devices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight in the browser currently only runs on Windows and Macs (with limited support on Linux with Moonlight). It does not run on iPhone, iPad (neither does it on Android or Windows Phone 7) and I'm not aware of any way you could make it run on those devices nor on any ways to port existing Silverlight code to the iOS devices.

If you want to support iPhone and iPad users to browse your site, you'll need to use HTM4 or HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is no way to run Silverlight on the iPad and iPhone -> http://www.theipadguide.com/faq/does-ipad-supportplay-microsoft-silverlight

About the browser and OS compatibility you can take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight#Operating_systems_and_web_browsers

Comment: For Macbook and MacAir, no problem for Silverlight?

Comment: Any SDK or software which could enable Silverlight browse on iPhone and iPad?

Comment: It runs very well on MacOS (i.e. MacBook/Air & co.). No way to make it work on ipad and iphone, now nor in the future (probably).